# Android Fitbit integration ask login every time

Tags: android, fitbit

I have integrated Fitbit in my application.I used chrome tabs for this purpose. My problem is once user logged in it doesn't show login page from next time and automatically redirects to my application. I don't want to function like this. I want if a user taps button and launch Fitbit page every time it should ask for user name and password. How can I do this? Thank you.